# Securing an HTTPS client

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm working on an app which uses NodeJS to (among other things) download some unencrypted PDF reports from the main website. Those resources are very much confidential so I need to make sure traffic is secured.

So from what I understand I need to buy and install an SSL certificate from a trusted CA and use `https.request(...)` in NodeJS to download the PDF files. But I have no idea how to ensure that the hosts file hasn't been tampered, or there's no on-going MITM attack, or even that the certificate is still valid, hadn't expired and is the one it has to be. How do I do this? Are there any config parameters?

---

Bonus if someone can please explain what prevents an attacker from buying an SSL certificate himself, host a local server with the same IP as the original site's external IP, and tamper a DNS's target to fool the user?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you open the SSL connection, check the peer certificate, and only if it hasn't expired, is the one you expect, etc., do you proceed. Once you're happy that you're talking to who you should be talking to, SSL provides security against replays, men-in-the-middle, etc. HTTPs does a little bit of that for you by insisting that the certificate subject match the hostname you connected to. But most of it is up to you.

Comment: Yes but do I have to implement all the comms between my script and the server? I mean does Node have any in-built functionality to deal with certificate validity, stuff like CA, expiry dates, self-signing, etc.?

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL I doubt that it needs to. The host browser already does all that, and JavaScript gets its services from the browser.

Comment: I'm asking if there's any certificate handler in nodejs https module.